# Directly access a put/update method on Laravel 5.1 without going into the edit view (MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to disable employees from a button on my index.blade.php page. Currently, the options of disabling employees (setting the status column in the database to false) is either to have an edit.blade.php view and update the value there, which is pretty standard for any laravel app or to have a new view for example, changestatus.blade.php, with the proper routes offcourse and update the value there. I am using the second implementation and it's working perfectly.

What i wanted to implement is to have a button on the index page which will change the status of the employee without going to a edit.blade.php or changestatus.blade.php page.

What i have tried
I have created new routes and created a button to link to the changestatus function

**Routes.php**

```
Route::put('employees/{employee}/changestatus', 'EmployeesController@changestatus')->name('employees.changestatus');
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');
```

**EmployeeController**

```
public function changestatus($EmployeeID)
{        
    $employee = Employee::find($EmployeeID);
    $employee->status = true;
    $employee->Save();        
}
```

On my view i created a button with the following link

{{ URL::route('employees.changestatus', $employee->EmployeeID) }}

When i click that link, i get the MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php error.

I even tried to change the Route::put to Route::Patch, but it's the same thing.
Is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? If so, how?

Comment: Why do you want such as terrible route `'employees/{employee}/changestatus'` ?

Comment: :) Any other way of implementing the idea without that terrible route?

Comment: Why not simply  `'employees/{employee}'` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen How would i differentiate it from the default methods (update, show and destroy) which use the same route URI?

Comment: Then, the only go should be form post, or specify the method via calls

Comment: Couldn't changing status be considered an update?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, It is an update but i didn't want to go to the edit.blade.php form.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen If i can do it from a new form called changestatus.blade.php, why i can't i do it from the index.blade.php view without going into the view.

Comment: I don't want you to use a new form, but just form helper which tells about the request type

Comment: Ah, I understand. In that case, there's nothing wrong with your route, but  perhaps use an ajax request so you never actually see it: `$.get(APP_URL + "/employees/" + employee_id + "/changeStatus/", function(data){ });`

Comment: Phil actually answered the question, but i guess his answer was deleted. I had to change the put to get on the routes.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a hyperlink, the web browser submits a `GET` request. Your route has been defined as being a `PUT` so that's why you're getting an exception.

You could either change the route to a `GET` by defining it like this:

```
Route::get('employees/{employee}/changestatus', 'EmployeesController@changestatus')->name('employees.changestatus');
```

Which isn't very ReSTful since a `GET` request should really only be used for returning a resource rather than modifying it.

Or, you could modify the button so that it submits a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('employees.changestatus', $employee->EmployeeID) }}">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <button type="submit">Button Text</button>
</form>
```

Note that you can't simply set the form method to `PUT` since this method isn't generally supported by web browsers. Laravel supports method spoofing which you can read all about here:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing